# R ggplot bar plot reordering happening in unknown groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reorderlist

I am trying to use reorder to plot barplot in ggplot and for some weird reason it is ordering small subgroups which I do not understand. My code looks something like this

```
df1 %>% ggplot(aes(x=reorder(state,-profit), y=profit)) + 
geom_col()
```

My bar plot looks like this
[image]

So looks like a small group on the right from ON to Unknown is reordered and similar groups (maybe) are ordered. I have no clue why that might happen. If I do not use reorder, ordering is random and if I use reorder(x=state,y=profit) without minus sign, then ordering is reversed. So it is showing some behavior but not all.

I used exactly same code on iris dataset and all seems to work perfectly. So I do not know why it does not work here. I cannot share the data (yet) but I want to know if anyone has any idea on what may be going on inside this data to reorder in such odd way. Is there any check or clean-up I need to do before? df1 has only these two columns.

Comment: Try with `reorder(state,-profit, FUN = sum)`. Reorder uses the mean by default.

Comment: Wow!! Spent last 2 hours on this and missed this trivial point which you solved in 2 seconds. Thanks so much...!! @stefan